# Help with prepared statements

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

Hey guys, I have recently heard that prepared statements are the best way to secure my website from mysql injections and what not. So I have a question, I can't seem to understand why this does not work:

```
$mysqli=new mysqli("localhost", "***", "***","***") or die(mysql_error());


              function checklogin($username, $password){


                $result = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?");
                $result->bind_param("s", $username);
                $result->execute();
```

I get the following error: Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in /var/www/JMToday/loginchk.php on line 45 Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /var/www/JMToday/loginchk.php on line 45

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're attempting to use a global variable ($mysqli) within a function. (The error message "undefined variable" is *incredibly* insightful in this instance.)

You either need to:

1. Declare the variable as a global. (i.e.: Add "`global $mysqli;`" as the first line within your checklogin function.)
2. Move the definition of $mysqli to within the checklogin function.

As a general bit of advice, I'd recommend reading the [variable scope](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) section of the PHP manual.